# fetch still returns Promise after await

Tags: javascript

I have this code that is not behaving as I expect it to. I've looked at several other questions, but the context seems not to be the same, so I'm asking a new one.

```js
async function loadDefaultConfig() {
    const response = await fetch("defaultSettings.json");
    console.log(response.json());
}
```

This is printing `Promise { <state>: "pending" }` in Firefox, but I was expecting not expecting to get a Promise after using `await`. How is `await` supposed to be used here in order to log the actual result of the `fetch`?

Comment: Long story short: Also `await` `response.json()`.

Comment: Or do `const responseObj = await fetch(...).then(r => r.json());` edit: fixed silly mistake

Comment: @lvar Thank you, that is... unintuitive, to say the least. I would never have guessed that my problem was actually the `.json()` and not the `await` not doing what I expected.